# Using min/max operator in integer programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, maximize

I am trying to optimize an objective function using integer programming, I have to use `Max` operator in my function, I want to know is there any way to deal with that?

Actually my question is similar to [Using min/max *within* an Integer Linear Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792139/using-min-max-within-an-integer-linear-program?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but is different in some aspects:

- All variables are binary.
- Note that `x4` and `x5` are presented in two place.
- One possible solution is using auxiliary variables like the answer of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792139/using-min-max-within-an-integer-linear-program?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but I am confused when using this solution for my example.

***Example:***

**Minimize**  `(c1 * x1) + (c2 * x2) + (c3 * x3) + Max(c4 * x4, c5 * x5) + (c6 * x4) + (c7 * x5)`

**subject to**
*some equality and inequality constraints*

Comment: May be @solvingPuzzles can help me!

Comment: It's refreshing when someone posts in the beginning why it differs from similar questions.

Comment: @Dennis Meng, sorry, I can't understand what you mean, my question isn't clear enough?

Comment: Not at all. I was remarking on how you mentioned at the beginning why this isn't exactly like the other question. It's a good thing. :)

Comment: It seems to me that you can use the technique in the other answer which you linked, are you running into problems?

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling, I can't understand how to use it, can u explain me plz?

Comment: @oMiD: Will try, see answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the approach in the question you linked. The expression

```
Max(c4 * x4, c5 * x5)
```

can be replaced by a variable `x6`, provided that you add the following additional constraints:

```
x6 >= c4 * x4
x6 >= c5 * x5
```

So you total set becomes:

```
Minimize (c1 * x1) + (c2 * x2) + (c3 * x3) + x6 + (c6 * x4) + (c7 * x5)
```

subject to:

```
some equality and inequality constraints
```

and the new requirements:

```
x6 >= c4 * x4
x6 >= c5 * x5
```

This works since `Max(c4 * x4, c5 * x5)` will either take the value `c4 * x4` or `c5 * x5`. The introduced variable `x6` will always be larger or equal to both of these expressions, and so will always be larger or equal to the total max-expression. When properly minimized, x6 will bottom out at the value of the max-expression. So when minimized, the two forms are equivalent.

Comment: thanks for your very  clear explanation, I totally get that :)